# Switching between Spring Profiles

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis, spring-profiles

I want to use `ArtemisTopic` in local profile and the `JmsTopic` in default profile. I have separate configurtion files for JMX stuff with Servicebus and ActiveMQ Artemis stuff. The idea is to use ActiveMQ Artemis for local development. How to achieve this?

```java
@Service
public class Publisher{

    private static final JmsTopic JmsTopic = new JmsTopic("raw");
    private static final ActiveMQTopic ArtemisTopic = new ActiveMQTopic("raw");

    public void send(Request request) {

        try {
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(ArtemisTopic, mapper.writeValueAsString(request), message -> {
                return message;
            });
        } catch (JsonProcessingException exception) {
            LOGGER.log(System.Logger.Level.ERROR, exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@Profile("local")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-local.properties")
public class MessagingConfigArtemis {

    private static final String ARTEMIS_BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";
    private static final String ARTEMIS_USERNAME = "artemis";
    private static final String ARTEMIS_PASSWORD = "artemis";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(ARTEMIS_BROKER_URL);
        connectionFactory.setUser(ARTEMIS_USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(ARTEMIS_PASSWORD);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(jmsConnectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory returnValue = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        returnValue.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> topicJmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory returnValue = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        returnValue.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        returnValue.setSubscriptionShared(true);
        returnValue.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        returnValue.setPubSubDomain(Boolean.TRUE);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `raw` as the topic name, and let the specific type of topic to your underlying mechanism. `convertAndSend("raw"....)` and be done.

Comment: with just raw its not working :/

Comment: Make sure you configurd the template for pubsub.. Assuming you are using the default configured one set `spring.jms.pubSubDomain=true`. This way it will send to a topic instead of a queue. If that doesn't work, please provide the actual error. What you don't want is leaking both abstractions into your code (like you have now), instead you just want the queue names. If nothing else works you should move them to `@Bean` methods which will create one or the other, or use it as a factory to create the proper topic. But it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: template is configured for pubsub.The thing is i am able to recieve using the @JmsListener on the reciever side( using Artemis) only if i send it to  the topic which is of the type ActiveMQTopic. if it is simply name, smh its not getting it. The ActiveMQTopic "Topic" exists in artemis console. But unless i use TOPIC (which is of the type ActiveMQTopic ) in convertAndSendmethod Argument it wont be delivered to the Topic.

Comment: I understand it will be simpler if i am able to send the message to the correct topic/queue using the name instead of using Specific type(like JmsTopic and ActiveMQTopic).But wonder why it is not working :(

Comment: Could you add configuration, also you aren't defining the `JmsTemplate` as a bean or something like that?

Comment: Why this configuration? This disables all the JMS auto configuration that Spring Boot does, your template is also not configured for pubsub. Ditch at least the `JmsTemplate` bean from this and configure the property mentioned before. You shouldn't be needing the listener container stuff either (unless you have different listeners for topics/queues) and ditch the `@EnableJms` . Finally the `@PropertySource` isn't needed as spring boot already loads that file.